# Error when trying to import a .dwg file in QGIS 3.34.2

Tags: qgis, autocad, importerror

I'm trying to import a .dwg file from a client into QGIS using Import/Export -> Import layers from DWG/DXF.

Then I'm selecting the correct source drawing & target package, however when I press the import button I get an error "error in block read process"

Anyone have any clue on what I can do from here?

Comment: Go back to whoever provided you the data and ask them to give you a `dxf`.

Comment: Try version 3.34.3. There were some problems with the builtin DWG importer up until very recently.